# fork with AND and OR operation

Tags: c, fork

Hello I am having hard time understanding below code - I tried to break it down and understand it but still no luck -

/*  Below code prints 20 times printf  */

```
int main()
{
    if (fork() && fork())
    {
        fork();
    }

    if (fork() || fork())
    {
        fork();
    }

    printf("hello world\n");

    return 0;
}
```

/* If I break and just print AND part - it prints 4 hello world - which kind of makes sense if I assume with AND operation only 1 fork got executed */

```
int main()
{
    if (fork() && fork())
    {
        fork();
    }

    printf("hello world\n");

    return 0;
}
```

/* how is the OR operation working - prints 5 Hello World ??*/

```
int main()
{
    if (fork() || fork())
    {
        fork();
    }

    printf("hello world\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I have gone through below references from SO site too but still couldnt figure this one out

[Understanding the fork() command Posix API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26747024/understanding-the-fork-command-posix-api?lq=1)

[Working of fork() in linux gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513242/working-of-fork-in-linux-gcc)

Comment: Hints: 1. If it's the child process `0` (false) is returned. 2. `&&` and `||` are short-circuit operators.

Comment: `||` is short-circuiting, similarly to `&&`. If the first argument of `||` is nonzero, it won't evaluate the second one.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant - Yes I did think about it - but in that case if I just take example of || operation - wouldnt it result in 4 printf ?  starts with main .. then from condition of if 1 fork and then 2 fork inside braces ?

Comment: It this to torture students?-S

Comment: As alluded to earlier, and assuming no errors, the return value from fork() is zero in the child process but is non-zero in the parent process (in this case it's the process ID of the child process).

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant - thanks for the link - that helps me understand the problem - should have searched harder -