# How fork() creates new process?

Tags: linux, unix

what is notion behind Unix design that a process can exist only with a valid parent? i.e, why each process has a parent process?

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking here. Each process has a parent because that's how Unix is designed. Many other parts rely on that fact (such as the system of return codes). If it were designed another way (for example as a system of independent and non-hierarchical objects like in the SmallTalk environment), then Unix would be something radically different and the question would be "why does each process not have a parent?" It was a design choice.

Comment: http://www.brianstorti.com/an_introduction_to_unix_processes/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does fork() work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15102328/how-does-fork-work)

Comment: It's not intuitively obvious, I think, why the whole fork/exec paradigm is a good design choice. Windows, for example, does not have a native notion of "forking" (so far as I recall), although it can be simulated. Tutorials, etc., that address processes in Linux seem to accept as a given that the way fork works does not call for any explanation -- it's just so familiar that nobody even thinks that things could have been organized differently. I don't know why the original Unix folks decided on the fork/exec model, but I would sure like to.