# Does if(fork()) create a child process?

Tags: c, multithreading, process, operating-system

I'm revising for an operating systems exam and currently trying to understand this processes question:

```
int main() 
{
    int v=0;
    
    if(fork()) 
    {
        v++;
        
        if(!fork())
        {
            fork();
            v--; 
        }
    } 
}
```

So the question asks to

> 1. Draw a tree reflecting the parent-child hierarchy of processes created when the program above is run.
> 2. How many separate copies of the integer variable v are created? Discuss what is the value of v at the end of the program for each of the processes in the tree.

The main thing I'm having an issue with is the

```
if(fork())
```

line in the code. From looking at other stack overflows I realised that

```
if(fork()) = if(fork() != 0)
```

but I'm still having difficulty understanding whether the first if statement creates a child process? Because thats the only way that the second if statement:

```
(!fork())
```

can be executed?

This is how far I've got with my current understanding of the question.
[screenshot of attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1C6Gl.png)
[image]

Hopefully the diagram is legible! I'd be really grateful for any hints or pointers with this.

Comment: Note:  You can break your question down into two completely independent questions:  (1) Does calling `fork()` create a child process? and (2) Does `if (some_function()) { ... }` call `some_function()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does fork() work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15102328/how-does-fork-work)

Answer (score 2):

Notice that `if (fork()) /*etc*/` is *exactly* the same as

```
pid_t newtmp = fork();
if (newtmp != 0) /*etc*/
```

where `newtmp` is a fresh (new) variable name not occurring in your program (you could use `x1`, `x2` etc.... provided it has no occurrence in your program), and `pid_t` is some integral type (probably `int`).

Once you rewrote your code with *explicit* and *unique* names given to result of `fork` you'll understand it better.

BTW, the code is poor taste. When you use `fork` you need to handle *three* cases:

- the `fork` failed (e.g. because your system has not enough memory, or because you exceeded some limits) and gives -1
- the `fork` succeeded in the child so gives 0
- the `fork` succeeded in the parent, so gives the pid of the child.

But when you code `if (fork())` you are forgetting -or handling incorrectly- the first case (failure). It can *rarely* happen.

Read *carefully* (and several times) the [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) man page. Notice that [fork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(system_call)) is difficult to understand.

Regarding limits, be aware of [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) (and the `ulimit` bash builtin).

Comment: I didn't actually write this code, it's from an exam question that I'm trying to understand.

Comment: Mentally transforming that code like I'm telling will help you in understanding it. Any occurrence of `fork` could create a process

Answer (score 0):

The answer is

```
if (fork ())
```

may or may determine whether a child process was created.

Go to the man page:

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html

We find that fork () returns three types of values:

- -1 => fork() failed
- 0 => return value in the child process
- a positive value => success and the PID of the child process.

Thus the test

```
if (fork ())
```

which is the same as

if (fork () != 0)

may succeed whether or not a child process was created. A competently written question would have said

```
if (fork () > 0)
```

Assuming everything works correctly:

```
int main() 
{
    int v=0;

    if(fork())  // Creates a child process that does nothing.
    {
        v++;

       if(!fork()) // Creates a child process that creates a child process (that then does nothing but decrement v).
       {
           fork();
          v--; 
       }
   }  
}
```