# Fork doesn't load the program in execv

Tags: process, pipe, fork, execv, socketpair

Below program neither load the program to child process nor prints "before" and "after".
However ps aux shows the creation of processes (but without loading args0 program). I am using PIPE defined as socketpair. args0[] holds executable name for the child program, args1[] holds the name of the child program. args2 and args3 are predefined values that doesn't change and should be sent to the children as arguments. you can assume char args2[] = "10" --> user input (digit) and converted to string. I just do not understand why at least printf("before") is not printed. i read about fflush and putting \n at every printf, and i did. so everything in my program 
is printed correctly up to this point.

I would truly appreciate your responses.

```
char args2[];
char args3[];
//creating pipe
int forkk(pipes *myPipe, server_message *m, char args0[],char args1[]) {
pid_t cpid;

//pipe passed myPipe[i]
if (PIPE(myPipe->fd) == -1) {
    perror("pipe error\n");
    return -1;
}
 fork();
 cpid=getpid();
if (cpid == -1) {
    perror("fork error\n");
    return -1;
}
if (cpid) {
    close(myPipe->fd[1]);
    return 1;//closing one end of parent

} else {

    for (int i = 3; i <= myPipe->fd[0]; i++) {
        close(i);
    }

    dup2(myPipe->fd[1], 0); //redirecting stdin of child
    dup2(myPipe->fd[1], 1); //redirecting stdout of child
    close(myPipe->fd[1]);
    myPipe->cpid = cpid;
    char *newargs[3];
    newargs[0]=args1;
    newargs[1]=args2;
    newargs[2]=args3;
    printf("before\n");
    //fflush(stdout);
    execv(args0,newargs);
    printf("after execv\n");
    write(myPipe->fd[0], &m, sizeof(server_message));  //send the server_msg immediately (pass an array or msg)

}
    return 2;
```

}

```
void main(){
....
scanf("%d %d", &width, &height);
sprintf(args2,"%d",height); //converting into to string
sprintf(args3,"%d",width);
char *args0 = "./prey";
char *args1 = "prey";
int r= forkk(&myPipes[2], &msg, args0,args1);
```

}

I cannot post the entire code as it is long and need explanation. I am most probably having a problem with pointer assignment that i wrongly think is the correct way. Thanks a lot for any kind of help

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Improve the code to get no warnings. [use the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/). Use also [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html). Don't forget to call `fflush` (probably `fflush(NULL);` ....) at appropriate places (probably before `fork`)

Comment: Read documentation of [execv(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execv.3.html); it usually does not return (except on failure)

Comment: I have no warnings. This is not a complete code so you might have. and you think i didnt read anything before posting. i was debugging with gdb for 5 hrs already. i read exec family group functions multiple times and i am passing correct arguments for execv , however there is smth i don't see and know and that is why i am posting here.

Comment: Did you use  `strace`? It should help. And you are expected to provide some [MCVE] in your question

Comment: some part of the program has no critical effect on forking and i think what i provided should be enough for the professional one to see the mistake (&msg and &myPipes also not directly affect the fork). I havent used strace, will use. program forks and never goes to the else part which is the problem itself

Comment: Next time, don't comment your question. But improve it by editing it much more

Comment: it was just another paraphrased version of the header statement.

Comment: Still it is better to edit your question than to comment it. BTW, if my answer fits, please accept and/or upvote it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>(spoiler: your `else` branch in your poorly named `forkk` is never taken!)</sup>

Read *carefully* documentation of [execv(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execv.3.html). You should provide a `NULL` terminated array.

> The execv(), execvp(), and execvpe() functions provide an array of
>          pointers to null-terminated strings that represent the argument list
>          available to the new program.  The first argument, by convention,
>          should point to the filename associated with the file being executed.
>          *The array of pointers must be terminated by a null pointer*.

So you should at least code:

```
char *newargs[4];
newargs[0]=args1;
newargs[1]=args2;
newargs[2]=args3;
newargs[3] = NULL; // mandatory last NULL pointer
execv(args0,newargs);
```

BTW, the first argument should generally be the program name. So you really want:

```
char *newargs[5];
newargs[0] = args0;
newargs[1]=args1;
newargs[2]=args2;
newargs[3]=args3;
newargs[4] = NULL; // mandatory last NULL pointer
execv(args0,newargs);
```

And the documentation also says

> The exec() functions return *only if* an error has occurred.

So in most cases, there is no point to continue here since `execv` won't return if successful. However, you need to catch the failure. I recommend after your `execv`

```
perror(arg0); // or perhaps perror("execv");
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

Your `write(myPipe->fd[0], &m, sizeof(server_message));` smells very bad. I see no point in doing that (only) when `execv` fails

BTW with [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) you would probably have caught such an error (missing terminating `NULL`  pointer for `execv`).

At last, you *always* should keep the result of [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49323923/841108). So replace:

```
 fork(); // WRONG
 cpid=getpid(); // always positive!
```

with `cpid = fork();`

Of course, you need to [handle the *three* cases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49323923/841108): `cpid== -1` (which you forgot to handle!), `cpid== 0`, `cpid> 0`.

Again, read carefully [getpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpid.2.html):

> getpid() returns the process ID (PID) of the calling process.

and (about `getpid` & `getppid`):

> These functions are *always* successful

So `getpid` *never* returns 0 (and that is why **your `else` branch in your `forkk`** poorly named function, containing the `execvp`, **never runs**). See also [credentials(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html).

Your  `void main()`  is also wrong. `main` should return an `int`. You generally define it as `int main(int argc, char**argv)` ...

PS. **Take the habit of reading *carefully* the documentation of *every* function you are using**.

<sup>Your `forkk` is very poorly named, too similar to the very important `fork` name.</sup>