# Trying to figure out how fork() works given in this context, but I don't seem to understand how the answer is achieved

Tags: c, multithreading, fork

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    int pid1=0, pid2=0, pid3=0;
    pid1 = fork() ;
    pid2 = fork() ;
    if(pid1 == 0 ) {
        printf("A\n") ;
    } else {
        pid3 = fork() ;
        printf("B\n") ;
    }
    if (pid2 != 0 && pid3 != 0) {
        printf("C\n") ;
    }
}
```

What is the total number of processes that will be created by running this program? How many of each character ‘A’ to ‘C’ will be printed out? Briefly explain why.

2 A’s 4 B’s 1 C (2 marks)

6 processes (including the original one) (2 marks)

Comment: "Run" the program with pen and paper

Comment: Draw a tree where each `fork()` forks the current branch into two, and mark one of those branches `0` (+ the name of the `pid*` variable). Go through all remaining code on both branches from that point on, writing the printed output. Then just count the number of branches you have at the end and the number of times you wrote each letter.

Comment: I would take a look at this excellent answer to a question about how fork works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34340479/1212725, and this good one: stackoverflow.com/a/15102710/1212725

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure it out with the help of you guys. The solution came with a diagram but it was confusing. However, using a binary tree I was able to create a better version of the diagram that explains the process better.

The same colour blocks represent the same process just at different points of the progress. The children of the binary tree represent the number of processes and the printed output is written from there. Check it out and thanks for all the help. I understand what was going on now.

[image]