# how to run multiple children with different tasks?

Tags: c, fork, pid, multiple-processes

My program has to create multiple children, i take the number of children from terminal. Then, I need to group them and every group has different tasks.

I created the children but the problem is that I can't give them separated tasks, I can't distinguish children. Only thing I can do is, every children works on the same part(like printing pids).

How can I separate them and give them specific tasks?

For example, first 4 children should call a function, other 3 should print something and other 3 should write to a file etc.

```
    pid_t pid[10];

    pid[0] = fork();
    if(pid[0] > 0)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            if(pid[i] > 0)
            {
                pid[i + 1] = fork();
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {   
        if(pid[i] == 0)
        {
            printf("child %d, parent %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
            exit(1);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should take a look at how the `fork()` function works. Here is the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), here a [useful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15102328/how-does-fork-work) and here a [useful tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fork-system-call/).

When you use `fork()` in your code, know that the child process continue from where the parent was. So when you call `fork()` in the first `for` loop, all the child processes continue the loop that the parent has begun. I don't think this is the behavior you expect.

Anyway, here's a possible solution for your problem. In this way your processes do some stuff divided in small groups. Note the `exit(0)` function at the end of the work. It is important to be sure that every process does only its work and not also its parent's work:

```
pid_t pid[10];

for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    pid[i] = fork();

    //First group            
    if (pid[i] == 0 && i < 4){
        //Insert here the code for the first group or call a fuction
        exit(0);
    }

    //Second group
    if (pid[i] == 0 && i >=4 && i < 8){
        //Insert here the code for the second group or call a fuction
        exit(0);
    }

    //Third group
    if (pid[i] == 0 && i >=8){
        //Insert here the code for the third group or call a fuction
        exit(0);
    }

    if (pid[i] < 0){
        perror("Something wrong with the fork");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe the typical term for processes is "parent", not "father".

Comment: in here, even we don't use, don't we create n^2 processes instead of n processes?

Comment: @Wokers no because every child calls the `exit()` function before calling a `fork()`

Comment: @Wokers why don't you take a look at the ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) section? I saw that you never accepted an answer and that you thank in comments, maybe it could be useful for you and the community

Answer (score 0):

```
int flag = 0;
flag |= (fork() == 0) << 0;
flag |= (fork() == 0) << 1;
flag |= (fork() == 0) << 2;
printf("this process works on problem %d\n", flag);
```